# Minimum Graal Polyglot example will not run

Tags: java, graalvm

I'm attempting to run a very simple GraalVM example but am running into a hard stop.

I simply want to add two values together using JavaScript.

```java
package com.example;

import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

public final class App {
    private App() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println( "starting up" );

        try ( Context context = Context.create() ){
            Value val = context.eval( "js", "10 + 2" );

            System.out.println( val.asInt() );
        }
        catch( Exception e ){
            System.out.println( e );
        }
    
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The program compiles fine but when I run it, I get the following output.

```
starting up
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine.getImpl (Engine.java:438)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build (Engine.java:736)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build (Context.java:1925)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create (Context.java:979)
    at com.example.App.main (App.java:13)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/Users/jacob/Dev/cfwasmer/cfwasmjava/cfwasm/target/classes/
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize (WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse (WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse (WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse (WindowsPath.java:92)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath (WindowsFileSystem.java:232)
    at java.nio.file.Path.of (Path.java:147)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$ClassPathIsolation.collectClassPathJars (Engine.java:1988)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$ClassPathIsolation.createIsolatedTruffleModule (Engine.java:1783)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$ClassPathIsolation.createIsolatedTruffle (Engine.java:1723)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$1.searchServiceLoader (Engine.java:1682)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$1.run (Engine.java:1668)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$1.run (Engine.java:1663)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:318)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine.initEngineImpl (Engine.java:1663)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$ImplHolder.<clinit> (Engine.java:186)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine.getImpl (Engine.java:438)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build (Engine.java:736)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build (Context.java:1925)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.create (Context.java:979)
    at com.example.App.main (App.java:13)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:840)
```

Since the program prints out "starting up" I know that it is executing partially. Why is it complaining about file paths when I'm not trying to access any files? How do I get it to run my JavaScript code?

EDIT:
I just tried running my example in a docker container and the program executed properly. My original test was in Windows. Can polyglot be used on windows? Do I need to do something to configure my environment?

Comment: FWIW, I believe the "InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index" message is because  `Class-Path:` entries in the jar `MANIFEST.MF` contain Windows drive letters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing changes that were introduced in the last release. All languages are now Maven dependencies, you can you  like so:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>polyglot</artifactId> 
    <version>23.1.0</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>js</artifactId> 
    <version>23.1.0</version> 
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

and then you can use them like

```
package org.example.embedding;

import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Source;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Set;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build()) {
            Set<String> languages = context.getEngine().getLanguages().keySet();
            for (String id : languages) {
                System.out.println("Initializing language " + id);
                context.initialize(id);
                switch (id) {
                    case "python":
                        context.eval("python", "print('Hello Python!')");
                        break;
                    case "js":
                        context.eval("js", "print('Hello JavaScript!');");
                        break;
                    case "ruby":
                        context.eval("ruby", "puts 'Hello Ruby!'");
                        break;
                    case "wasm":
                        // with wasm we compute factorial
                        context.eval(Source.newBuilder("wasm", Main.class.getResource("factorial.wasm")).build());
                        Value factorial = context.getBindings("wasm").getMember("main").getMember("fac");
                        System.out.println("wasm: factorial(20) = " + factorial.execute(20L));
                        break;
                    case "java":
                        // with Java we invoke System.out.println reflectively.
                        Value out = context.getBindings("java").getMember("java.lang.System").getMember("out");
                        out.invokeMember("println", "Hello Espresso Java!");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can look at https://github.com/graalvm/polyglot-embedding-demo for a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already added those dependencies to my `pom.xml`. I don't think that is the issue. I was able to run the program on Linux without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was originally a bug in our class-path isolation that is only triggered on Windows. The bug was fixed in 23.1.1, but with 23.1.2 also the class-path isolation code is gone, so you should no longer have any issues.

In other words, just use these dependencies instead:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>polyglot</artifactId> 
    <version>23.1.2</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>js</artifactId> 
    <version>23.1.2</version> 
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```